# Primefaces dataexporter not working

Tags: maven, jsf-2, primefaces, itext, data-export

I am using primefaces 5.1. I am trying to simply export data as pdf from datatable with primefaces. To use dataexporter of primefaces 5.1 it is necessary to add itext 2.1.7 dependency. My project is a maven-based project. I added the depenendency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
  <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

The relevant part of code is:

```
<p:commandButton value="Export" ajax="false">  
     <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="cars"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

The datatable works fine. I don't think the code is the problem. Anyway, this is the error I get from the glassfish 4.1 console:

```
    Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for     servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.Phrase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExporterFactory.getExporterForType(ExporterFactory.java:34)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:88)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: And you stopped server, cleaned & builded & deployed? Netbeans sometimes need "build with dependencies" as far as I can see. If you expand the builded war, is the jar then in /WEB-INF/lib/ ?

Comment: I've sometimes had similar problems, solved by manually copying the missing jar to the server; /glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext (in fact both inside and outside of ext-folder, never found out which one worked). But its not the best solution

Comment: It didn't what you suggested. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, If someone else need it!!

```
<h:commandLink id="pdf">
                <p:graphicImage  url="resources/demo/images/pdf.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl"                                          fileName="reporteTimbre" preProcessor="#{fullTimeView.preProcessPDF}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

and,

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
     <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

Also by the way...

```
public void preProcessPDF(Object document) throws IOException, BadElementException, DocumentException {
            Document pdf = (Document) document;
            pdf.open();
            pdf.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            pdf.setPageCount(0);


            ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            String logo = externalContext.getRealPath("") + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "demo" + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "gadCuenca.png";

            pdf.add(Image.getInstance(logo));
     }
```